# Does GWT eliminate need for front end web Developer?

Tags: gwt

I'm a front end developer(html,css,js), and it looks like my group is going to be using GWT framework for the web based application that is pretty much the only product I was hired to work on.   from what i am seeing, its really for Java developers to create applications, which then create a JavaScript that renders the page.

Should i seriously start looking for another job? Do I need to be a Java developer now?

Answer (score 1):

If your company is happy with the default look of GWT or a library for GWT the needs for custom html/css/javascript will likely be much less prominent.

However if they want to have applications look a very specific way they will still need somebody who has your skillsets (possibly more than before).  If you know what you do now plus some GWT/Java you will be invaluable as to truly customize the look of a GWT application you need to understand both sides.  The bottom line is that learning GWT/Java is a really good idea for somebody in your position, luckily you can skip a lot of what most Java devs need to know and just learn to use GWT.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the strengths / weaknesses of your group, but pretty much the point of GWT is to eliminate complexities of programming in Javascript and being able to use Java instead.  I had no Javascript knowledge when I started using GWT 9 months ago, and pretty much still have no Javascript knowledge - I don't need it.  Granted, I've started using some Javascript wrappers, but that's a small subset of GWT.

CSS on the other hand is vital to any GWT application. It defines nearly everything about the placement and the look and feel of everything in an app.  Yes, it can also be done programmatically (though it shouldn't), but CSS is still the basis of how everything appears and is placed.  For straight-up HTML, you don't need much - I use divs, but everything else is a GWT widget.

Note: this is all based on my first (and only) ongoing enterprise-level GWT app for which I am the sole developer.  Hopefully it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no. GWT certainly does not eliminate the need for someone good at CSS, and depending on the development pattern your team follows, doing HTML to go with it is still needed too.

All that said, if you are familiar with JavaScript, you will likely find working with GWT pretty easy, and for large projects the Java languages has a number of big advantages over JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking at 3 options (based on  your info):

- learn Java to compliment your solid skill set to become proficient front end GWT developer;
- keep doing what you are doing at your current job: with no Java you are looking at very limited role of UI designer primarily using GWT UIBinder / CSS / HTML and possibly JavaScript;
- look for another job.